# Python: Requests over Tor , Enabling rotating IP - missing torrc file

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, identity, tor

I'm trying to set up requests over Tor, while rotating over IPs.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875657/7326714) explaining everything quite clear. I've set it up and am able to request via Tor. That is, via one single IP.

To allow for rotation, I need to uncomment some lines in a file named `torrc`, as described in the answer. However, this file does not exist on my computer.

I've checked tor.stackoverflow and found [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/cant-find-torrc-file-on-mac), however its there neither. I posed a [question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/14341/16743) on tor.stackoverflow, but the only comment I got so far hasn't helped. It also seems tor.stackoverflow isn't that active.

I hope someone here had the same issue and is able to help me. I'm working on Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.3.

Comment: What command did you use to install tor ?

Comment: By `sudo port install tor`, as stated in the [official documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en).

Comment: have you checked this location : ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/torrc ??

Comment: Yes, I did. I do not have `TorBrowser-Data` in the `~/Library/Application Support/`.

Comment: check these locations also : /etc/tor/torrc  and /etc/torrc

Comment: Thanks, but I already did all of that, as stated in my question.

Comment: remember that you will have a torrc.sample which you will be needed to copy as torrc

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the answer in your question.

The torrc sample should be located at `/opt/local/etc/tor/torrc.sample` as per the documentation and you can copy that to some other place and start tor using the copied torrc.

```
tor -f </path/to/torrc> [args]
```

In case you do not find the sample torrc, you can get one from the [official svn source](https://svn.torproject.org/svn/tor/tags/tor-0_2_0_34/src/config/torrc.sample.in).

If you want to find out what your currently running `tor` instance is using as it's `torrc`, I checked the running processes on my system (`ps -ef | grep tor` for Ubuntu) and found the following

```
debian-+  1373     1  0 09:30 ?        00:00:16 /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0
```

Maybe you can do something similar on your system and if lucky, get the `-f` argument and thus the default torrc location.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So far I've managed to copy the `torrc.sample`, edit it and save it as `torrc`. I've tried the `tor -f </path/to/torrc> [args]` in Terminal, but I'm not sure it worked. I did `tor -f <mypath/torrc> [args]`, i.e. I did not change `[args]`, is that ok?

Comment: You can drop the `[args]` part entirely unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: `tor -f <mypath/torrc> [args]` gives `No such file or directory`. However, the torrc file is there and my path is correct. 
`tor -f <mypath/torrc>` gives `syntax error near unexpected token newline`. `tor -f <mypath> [args]` gives a new prompt. I'm lost.

Comment: Let's take this to the [python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) where you can give me your torrc to look at.

Comment: Ok, I'm in the room now.