# Scrapy with Privoxy and Tor: how to renew IP

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, tor

I am dealing with Scrapy, Privoxy and Tor. I have all installed and properly working. But Tor connects with the same IP everytime, so I can easily be banned. Is it possible to tell Tor to reconnect each X seconds or connections?

Thanks!

EDIT about the configuration:
For the user agent pool i did this: http://tangww.com/2013/06/UsingRandomAgent/ (I had to put a _ *init* _.py file as it is said in the comments), and for the Privoxy and Tor I followed http://www.andrewwatters.com/privoxy/ (I had to create the private user and private group manually with the terminal). It worked :)

My spider is this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class YourCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spider_name"
    start_urls = [
    'https://example.com/listviews/titles.php',
    ]
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # go to the urls in the list
        s = Selector(response)
        page_list_urls = s.xpath('///*[@id="tab7"]/article/header/h2/a/@href').extract()
        for url in page_list_urls:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)

        # Return back and go to bext page in div#paginat ul li.next a::attr(href) and begin again
        next_page = response.css('ul.pagin li.presente ~ li a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    # For the urls in the list, go inside, and in div#main, take the div.ficha > div.caracteristicas > ul > li
    def parse_following_urls(self, response):
        #Parsing rules go here
        for each_book in response.css('main#main'):
            yield {
                'editor': each_book.css('header.datos1 > ul > li > h5 > a::text').extract(),
            }
```

In settings.py I have an user agent rotation and privoxy:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        #user agent
        'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
        'spider_name.comm.rotate_useragent.RotateUserAgentMiddleware' :400,
        #privoxy
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
        'spider_name.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100
    }
```

In middlewares.py I added:

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```

And I think that's all…

EDIT II ---

Ok, I changed my middlewares.py file as in the blog @Tomáš Linhart said  from:

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```

To

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])

    def set_new_ip():
        with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
            controller.authenticate(password='tor_password')
            controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

But now is really slow, and doesn't appear to change the ip… I did it ok or is something wrong?

Comment: this project on github explains how to scrap anonymoulsy https://github.com/WiliTest/Anonymous-scrapping-Scrapy-Tor-Privoxy-UserAgent

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [blog post](http://dm295.blogspot.cz/2016/02/tor-ip-changing-and-web-scraping.html) might help you a bit as it deals with the same issue.

**EDIT:** Based on concrete requirement (new IP for each request or after *N* requests), put appropriate call to `set_new_ip` in `process_request` method of the middleware. Note, however, that call to `set_new_ip` function doesn't have to always ensure new IP (there's a link to the FAQ with explanation).

**EDIT2:** The module with `ProxyMiddleware` class would look like this:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

def _set_new_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password='tor_password')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        _set_new_ip()
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```

Comment: Hm. So I have to install stem, and then, as in **Changing IP address**  use the `def set_new_ip():` function inside my spider code importing stem. Is this correct? Or the `def set_new_ip():` has to go in a middleware?

Comment: @Nikita What exactly is your requirement? To get new IP for each spider run, or even for each request?

Comment: For each request or every x number of request. Is to make bore difficult to be banned by IP.

Comment: When you say «spider run», you mean each run of the loop inside the spider, or each time the spider is opened?

Comment: And how do you have the Scrapy + Privoxy + Tor combination set up?

Comment: I'll update the question with all the configuration!

Comment: @Nikita Edited the answer to reflect your addition to question.

Comment: Thank you! This is for new IP for each request (or after N requests). Is this what people do to avoid getting banned?

Comment: @Nikita It is one of the ways, others are mentioned [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned).

Comment: Ok, I tried, but it doesn't works very well. I don't know if I understood properly what has to be done. Question updated!

Comment: @Nikita You are missing the call to `set_new_ip` in your `process_request` method.

Comment: So I have to add `set_new_ip `  in a new line after the sentence `spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])`, yep?

Comment: Yes. Also, how do you check the IP address Tor connects with?

Comment: I scrap my website :)

Comment: Hm, if I add `set_new_ip ()` or `set_new_ip` in a new line after `spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])` it returns an error `NameError: global name 'set_new_ip' is not defined`.

Comment: If you define it as an instance method of your `ProxyMiddleware` class (as in your case), you need to reference it using `self`. Otherwise define it as a function above the class definition and no need for `self` then.

Comment: Ahm, so the idea is that when the method `def process_request(self, request, spider):` reach the end, I have to call the method  `def set_new_ip():` inside the same class (self), with `self.set_new_ip()`. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you! You changed the order of the methods. Is it important?

Comment: @Nikita The order is not important, call to `_set_new_ip` controlls Tor which is unrelated to the middleware processing.

Comment: Hi, I used your code; sadly I am having an error: `SocketError: [Errno 61] Connection refused`, and I don't know if this is related to the port used or what. A new question will be better for that. Thanks!

Comment: I opened a new question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036812/scrapy-privosy-and-tor-socketerror-errno-61-connection-refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036812/scrapy-privosy-and-tor-socketerror-errno-61-connection-refused) :)

Answer (score 12):

> But Tor connects with the same IP everytime

That is a [documented Tor feature](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor):

> An important thing to note is that **a new circuit does not necessarily
> mean a new IP address**. Paths are randomly selected based on heuristics
> like speed and stability. There are only so many large exits in the
> Tor network, so it's not uncommon to reuse an exit you have had
> previously.

That's the reason why using the code below can result in reusing the same IP address again.

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller


with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate(password='tor_password')
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

https://github.com/DusanMadar/TorIpChanger helps you to manage this behavior. Disclaimer - I wrote `TorIpChanger`.

I've also put together a guide on how to use Python with Tor and Privoxy: https://gist.github.com/DusanMadar/8d11026b7ce0bce6a67f7dd87b999f6b.

Here's an example of how you can use `TorIpChanger` (`pip install toripchanger`) in your `ProxyMiddleware`.

```
from toripchanger import TorIpChanger


# A Tor IP will be reused only after 10 different IPs were used.
ip_changer = TorIpChanger(reuse_threshold=10)


class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ip_changer.get_new_ip()
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```

Or, if you want to use a different IP after 10 requests, you can do something like below.

```
from toripchanger import TorIpChanger


# A Tor IP will be reused only after 10 different IPs were used.
ip_changer = TorIpChanger(reuse_threshold=10)


class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    _requests_count = 0

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self._requests_count += 1
        if self._requests_count > 10:
            self._requests_count = 0 
            ip_changer.get_new_ip()

        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```