# Scrapy, privoxy and Tor: SocketError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, tor

I am using Scrapy with Privoxy and Tor. Here is my previous question [Scrapy with Privoxy and Tor: how to renew IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009940/scrapy-with-privoxy-and-tor-how-to-renew-ip/45010141?noredirect=1#comment77037968_45010141), and here is the spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class YourCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "****"
    start_urls = [
    'https://****.com/listviews/titles.php',
    ]
    allowed_domains = ["****.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # go to the urls in the list
        s = Selector(response)
        page_list_urls = s.xpath('///*[@id="tab7"]/article/header/h2/a/@href').extract()
        for url in page_list_urls:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)

        # Return back and go to bext page in div#paginat ul li.next a::attr(href) and begin again
        next_page = response.css('ul.pagin li.presente ~ li a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    # For the urls in the list, go inside, and in div#main, take the div.ficha > div.caracteristicas > ul > li
    def parse_following_urls(self, response):
        #Parsing rules go here
        for each_book in response.css('main#main'):
            yield {
                'editor': each_book.css('header.datos1 > ul > li > h5 > a::text').extract(),
            }
```

In settings.py I have an user agent rotation and privoxy:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        #user agent
        'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
        '****.comm.rotate_useragent.RotateUserAgentMiddleware' :400,
        #privoxy
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
        '****.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100
    }
```

In middlewares.py I added:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

def _set_new_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password='tor_password')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        _set_new_ip()
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```

If I take out the `def _set_new_ip():` method of the class in middlewares.py (and the call to it in `class ProxyMiddleware(object):` the spider works. But I want the spider to call for a new IP each time, and that's why I added it. The problem is that each time I try to run the spider it returns an error `SocketError: [Errno 61] Connection refused`, with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 37, in process_request
    response = yield method(request=request, spider=spider)
  File "/Users/nikita/scrapy/***/***/middlewares.py", line 71, in process_request
    _set_new_ip()
  File "/Users/nikita/scrapy/***/***/middlewares.py", line 65, in _set_new_ip
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/control.py", line 998, in from_port
    control_port = stem.socket.ControlPort(address, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/socket.py", line 372, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/socket.py", line 243, in connect
    self._socket = self._make_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/socket.py", line 401, in _make_socket
    raise stem.SocketError(exc)
SocketError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
2017-07-11 15:50:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Maybe the problem is in the port used in `with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:`, but I am not sure. If anybody has an idea that would be fantastic…

EDIT---

Ok, if I go to the browser and go to http://127.0.0.1:8118/, it sais:

```
503 
This is Privoxy 3.0.26 on localhost (127.0.0.1), port 8118, enabled
Forwarding failure
Privoxy was unable to socks5-forward your request http://127.0.0.1:8118/ through localhost: SOCKS5 request failed

Just try again to see if this is a temporary problem, or check your forwarding settings and make sure that all forwarding servers are working correctly and listening where they are supposed to be listening.
```

So maybe it is related to the configuration of SOCKS5… Anyone knows?

Comment: Look [here](https://stem.torproject.org/api/connection.html) about how to connect to Tor using `stem`.

Comment: Ok, in this web they talk about the `authenticate()` function. In the example they give first they make a `control_socket = stem.socket.ControlPort(port = 9051)`, and after that then `stem.connection.authenticate(control_socket)`. Should I put both of them in the `ProxyMiddleware` class?

Comment: Ok, I understand that I have to call the `connect()` function somewhere, but, where? I tried some options but none were succesful…

Comment: I have something, update the question.

Comment: Are you sure you have Tor running and the Privoxy setup with Tor is correct and working?

Comment: I think yes, because if I go to [https://check.torproject.org/](https://check.torproject.org/) it sais Tor is running, and if I go to [http://p.p/](http://p.p/) it sais Privoxy is running as well, and in [http://www.ip2location.com/](http://www.ip2location.com/) I can see that the connections that are hitting the site are from a proxy (also I can see the connections from the IP of another proxy when I scrap a site I manage).

Comment: this github explains how to scrap  anonymously https://github.com/WiliTest/Anonymous-scrapping-Scrapy-Tor-Privoxy-UserAgent

Answer (score 2):

My guess is either:

1. **Tor is not running**. To make sure if Tor is running, run `ps` (e.g., `ps -ax | grep tor`) and `netstat`(e.g., for mac: `netstat -an | grep 'your tor portnumber'`. For linux, replace `-an` with `-tulnp`) on terminal to see if Tor is really running.
2. **You didn't set up the forwwarding setting corectly**. Based on the 503 error message, it looks like you didn't set up the forwarding rule correctly (if Tor is running). In the config file of Privoxy, make sure `forward-socks5t   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .` is uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        def _set_new_ip():
            with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
                controller.authenticate(password='PASSWORDHERE')
                controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).