# When tor is set to obtain rotating IP, the “login” of the webpage interreputs even if the IP has not already change

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, tor

### Introduction

First of all I did try the solutions of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009940/scrapy-with-privoxy-and-tor-how-to-renew-ip) and it does not work in my case. I mean the IP is rotating, but I obtained `empty socket content` message, besides the website was scraped but not as I want because there are informations I can **scrape** only if I am logged.
So I set `torcc` file to obtain a rotating IP with `MaxCircuitDirtiness 20` and it is rotating, without socks problem this time but I finish fastly to be unlogged, then I do not obtain the informations I am interested about.

That is the kind of item I **scrape**

```
{'_id': 'Bidule',
'field1': ['A','C','D','E'], #it requires to be logged to the page
'field2': 'truc de bidule',
'field3': [0,1,2,3],#it requires to be logged to the page
'field4': 'le champ quatre'}
```

It works for the first items but there is a moment it goes bad as:

```
{'_id': 'Machine',
'field1': [], #empty because not logged
'field2': 'truc de machine',
'field3': [],#empty because not logged
'field4': 'le champ quatre'}
```

### when it goes bad?

Below you have an illustration of what happens during one of my **scrape**, referring to the log file and terminal informations.

```
IP: 178.239.176.73 #first item scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #second item scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #third item scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #fourth item scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #fifth item scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #sixth item scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #seventh item scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #eighth item scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #nineth item NOT scraped as expected
IP: 178.239.176.73 #and item NOT scraped as expected until the end
IP: 178.239.176.73
IP: 178.239.176.73
IP: 162.247.74.27
IP: 162.247.74.27
IP: 162.247.74.27
IP: 162.247.74.27
IP: 162.247.74.27
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
IP: 178.175.132.227
```

The big deal is even if the IP has not already changed, it unlogs me, then my items are not interesting anymore. So I do not understand why this happens.

Note that when it is not set to make a rotating IP it works well, no issue, but I want a set rotating IP.

I tried to include the parameter `COOKIES_ENABLED = True` because I wondered if to avoid cookies makes lose my login to the webpage, but that's not the reason apparently. So I am still wondering what is the cause.

### code if you want to test and to make results reproducible and to help:

`scrapy startproject project`

the project directory's organization:

```
project #directory
 |_ scrapy.cfg #file
 |__project #directory
     |_ __init__.py (empty) #file
     |_ items.py (unnecessary to test) #file
     |_ middlewares.py #file
     |_ pipelines.py (unnecessary to test)#file
     |_ settings.py #file
     |__ spiders #directory
          |_ spiders.py #file
```

`middlewares.py`:

```
from scrapy import signals
import random
from scrapy.conf import settings

class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ua = random.choice(settings.get('USER_AGENT_LIST'))
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = settings.get('HTTP_PROXY')
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])

class ProjectSpiderMiddleware(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_spider_input(self, response, spider):
        return None

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        for i in result:
            yield i

    def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):
        pass

    def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
        for r in start_requests:
            yield r

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)

 class ProjectDownloaderMiddleware(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        pass

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
```

`settings.py`:

```
USER_AGENT_LIST = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/43.0.2442.991',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/42.0.2393.94',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/48.0.2685.52'
]

#proxy for polipo
HTTP_PROXY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
#retry if needed
RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_TIMES = 5  # initial response + 2 retries = 3 requests
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [401, 403, 404, 408, 500, 502, 503, 504]
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
COOKIES_ENABLED = True #commented or not did not work for me
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'project.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'project.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
```

`spiders.py` in `spiders` directory:

```
import scrapy
from re import search

class ChevalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fiche_cheval"
    start_urls = ['https://www.paris-turf.com/compte/login']
    def __init__ (self,username=None, mdp=None):
        self.username= username #create a fake account by yourself
        self.mdp = mdp

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('[name="_csrf_token"]::attr(value)').get()
        data_log = {
                '_csrf_token': token,
                '_username': self.username,
                '_password': self.mdp
                 }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=data_log, callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        liste_ch=['alexandros-751044','annette-girl-735523','citoyenne-743132','everest-748084','goudurix-687456','lady-zorreghuietta-752292','petit-dandy-671825','ritvilik-708712','scarface-686119','siamese-713651','tic-tac-toe-685508',
        'velada-745272','wind-breaker-755107','zodev-715463','ballerian-813033','houpala-riquette-784415','jemykos-751551','madoudal-736164','margerie-778614','marquise-collonges-794335','mene-thou-du-plaid-780155']#Only a sample of thousands ids.
        url=['https://www.paris-turf.com/fiche-cheval/'+ch for ch in liste_ch]
        for link,cheval in zip(url,liste_ch):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link,
                callback=self.page_cheval,
                meta={'nom':cheval}
            )
    def page_cheval(self, response):
        def lister_valeur(x_path,x_path2):
            """Here a customed function to get value none even if the tag
           does not exist in the page. Then the list fields have the same
           length. Important for my applications."""
            liste_valeur=[]
            for valeur in response.xpath(x_path):
                val=valeur.xpath(x_path2).extract_first()
                if val is None or val =="" or val=="." or val=="-" or val==" ":
                    liste_valeur.append(None)
                else:
                    liste_valeur.append(val)
            return liste_valeur

        cat_course1,cat_course2="//html//td[@class='italiques']","text()"
        cat_course=lister_valeur(cat_course1,cat_course2)#'Course A', 'Course B', ...
        gains1,gains2="//html//td[@class='rapport']","a/text()"
        gains=lister_valeur(gains1,gains2)#'17 100', '14 850', '0',...
        gains=[
        int(search(r'(\d{1,10})', gain.replace('\n','').replace(' ','').replace('.','')).group(1))
        if search(r'(\d{1,10})', gain.replace('\n','').replace(' ','').replace('.','')) != None else 0
        for gain in gains
    ]
        _id_course=response.xpath("//html//td[1]/@data-id").extract()

        item={
            '_id':response.request.meta['nom'],
            'cat_de_course':cat_course,
            'gains':gains,
            'id_de_course':_id_course
        }
        yield scrapy.Request('http://checkip.dyndns.org/', callback=self.checkip, dont_filter=True)
        yield item
    def checkip(self, response):
        print('IP: {}'.format(response.xpath('//body/text()').re('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')[0]))
        logging.warning('IP: {}'.format(response.xpath('//body/text()').re('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')[0]))
```

To launch the spider:

`scrapy crawl fiche_cheval -a username=yourfakeemailaccount -a mdp=password -o items.json -s LOG_FILE=Project.log`

some notes:
In the last crawl I did few minutes ago, while the IP was changing, the items were all okay **except the last one**, so if your run it once and you see every item to be okay it is certainly not a reproducible result when you launch it again.

#### Tor and Polipo configurations:

`/etc/tor/torrc` file:

```
MaxCircuitDirtiness 20
SOCKSPort 9050
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
```

`/etc/tor/torsocks.conf` file:

```
TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9050
```

`/etc/polipo/config` file:

```
logSyslog = true
logFile = /var/log/polipo/polipo.log
socksParentProxy = localhost:9050
diskCacheRoot=""
disableLocalInterface=true
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, Tor: 0.3.2.10 (git-0edaa32732ec8930) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0g, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd 1.3.3., I do not find way to check polipo version.

### UPDATE

I made a loop. I mean when the item is not as expected it goes back to `parse` it log again because I checked in the loop if `data_log` was still ok during the loop and it was when it was used again.
So when I login I do not obtain the items as expected. This is very strange.

Comment: You shouldn't use Tor for this. use rotating http or socks proxies.

Comment: @pguardiario what does it mean exactly please? Besides, are sure it solves the problem of login?

Comment: Maybe they have server side bot detection and are terminating the login session automatically due to unusual behavior.  Sometimes very strict sessions will auto log you out of the user agent changes between requests.

Comment: @drew010 that's unlikely because as I mentioned the IP hasn't change that the items go wrong. The only thing that variates is to set a rotating IP as the possibilty in the `middlewares.py`: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009940/scrapy-with-privoxy-and-tor-how-to-renew-ip) or to write `MaxCircuitDirtiness X` in `torrc`. So what it could be seen as unusual by the website's server?

Comment: A few easy to detect bot patterns: HTTP requests from Tor, the timing of the requests, logging in and/or crawling without loading any images or executing Javascript, user agent changes between requests with the same cookie and IP. Less likely, some of those user agent strings are really outdated which may be a red flag.

Comment: @drew010 if your assumption was true:"detect bot patterns: HTTP requests from Tor, the timing of the requests..." it won't, I repeat won't, work when  `MaxCircuitDirtiness 20` is off. That is the **only** parameter that changes **and** it goes bad even when the IP has not changed. But it works when it is off. And the website accepts the bots you can check it yourself because you have the address.