# Getting Tor ControlPort to work

Tags: python, tor, stem

I have installed Tor to run as a service on my windows machine and I am trying to make requests in python through the Stem package. In my torrc file I have specified ControlPort as 9051 and set a HashedControlPassword. When I run netstat, I see that Tor is running on localhost:9050 but there is nothing listening to port 9051. As a result, when I try to connect to the ControlPort in python:

```
Controller.from_port(port=9051)
```

results in a

```
[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I've tried restarting the service, I even reinstalled Tor Browser but nothing seems to make the ControlPort work.

Comment: Firewall issue? When you get it working you may want to use a `context_manager` form: `with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller: controller.authenticate(password="<password>")`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the problem you have is because you are running tor as a Windows Service.
The issue is that when tor is installed as a service, for whatever reason the Control Port is not enabled.
To fix your issue, open your terminal, navigate to the tor directory and type the following commands:

```
tor --service remove
tor --service install -options ControlPort 9051
```

Now, tor is installed as a service AND the ControlPort is enabled on port 9051.
If you type "netstat -an" you will now see that port 9051 is open.

You will then be able to use Stem to connect to the ControlPort.

I hope this helps.

Peace.
Sat Cit Ananda.

Comment: Yeah, it is strange, I lost a whole afternoon figuring out the cause of the issue and how to resolve it. Glad I could help you, and maybe other who will face the same issue in the future.

Comment: there are several tor folders, the path needed is `...\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor`

Comment: I'm not seeing port "9051" open after following the installation process and entering in "netstat -an" in the terminal. I'm also not seeing port "9050" which is throwing a connection error when making the initial "session.get()" request... Any input is appreciated. You're my hero!

Comment: I keep getting "Service failed to start : An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request." error, but cant figure out why, any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Solution that worked for me (windows 10) with a bit of tweaking from `Sat Cit Ananda`'s answer:

```
[at your terminal]
cd ...\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor
tor --service remove
tor --service install -options ControlPort 9151
netstat -an
```

Tor service runs at default port `9150` and ControlPort on `9151`.
You should be able to see local address `127.0.0.1:9150` and `127.0.0.1:9151` when you run `netstat -an`.