# BeautifulSoup webpage have protection and prettify() return no data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some data from a wine website.

But I can not assess the data and there have a usage violation message.

The url : https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/drc/2013

The prettify() result something like that:

```
<div id="bodycontainer">
<div class="colmask contentparent">
 <div id="colheader">
  <div class="colmask articlecontainer">
   <div class="colmidtemp3">
    <div class="collefttemp3">
     <div class="col1wraptemp3">
      <div class="col1temp3">
       <div>
        <h1 style="margin:50px 0 0">
         Usage Violation
        </h1>
        <div style="margin-bottom:50px;padding:50px 10px;background-color:#FFFACD">
         <h2 style="font-size:1.4em">
          Blocked
         </h2>
         <p style="font-size:1.2em">
          The IP Address [xx.xxx.xxx.xx] you are using has been used in violation of Wine-Searcher's usage guidelines.
          <b>
           If you think you have received this message in error restart your web browser and retry accessing wine-searcher.com.
          </b>
         </p>
         <p style="font-size:1.2em">
          To re-gain access to Wine-Searcher please
          <a href="mailto:wsexcessiveuse@wine-searcher.com?subject=Blocked IP=1 ID=PVBXC7PJCM80025">
           Contact Us
          </a>
          .
         </p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Is there any possible ways to get the data from the url? Thank you so much.

My coding here :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import bs4
import re
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

name = "Wine.txt"
k = open(name, "w", encoding='utf-8')

Stat_url = "https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/drc/2012"
page = requests.get(Stat_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')

k.write(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Can you post the requests that you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they added some protection to their page to prevent that, what you try to do ;)
They sell access via API https://www.wine-searcher.com/api.lml and allow in a trial 100 calls in 5 days. Maybe this is enough for you?

I would guess that BeautifulSoup is trying to many requests in to few time? (Maybe limit it to one per 10 seconds and let it run overnight?)
Can the agent-id in BS be changed to something more common like a regular browser agent-id?

Comment: Try the basic stuff like a nice header with a proper user agent. Pages like that screen for user agents and requests sends off "python requests...."-ish by itself.  Take a look at the: https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/ And if you need proxies grab one from gimmeproxy. The have a free api that's easy to use

Comment: Thanks marcel, when it comes to the request, it is always show the same blocked result no matter how many request i submit. And you have said that agent-id can be similar to normal id. Thank you for you idea and I will try.

Comment: Thanks jlaur, Base on your comment, If I want to bypass the website like that wine page, is there any other factor affect the issue?

Comment: @Kenny the link in my comment includes inputs for exactly that. Try googling around (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=avoid+ip+blocking+with+web+scraping)