# I have a Python code to scraping a web site web,But the program did not provide me with any information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is `book.py`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ceresbookshop.com/fr/'
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find the elements containing book names and prices
    book_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-details')

    # Extract names and prices for the first 10 books
    for i, book_element in enumerate(book_elements[:10], start=1):
        book_name = book_element.find('a', class_='product-title').text.strip()
        book_price = book_element.find('span', class_='price').text.strip()
        print(f'Book {i}:')
        print(f'Name: {book_name}')
        print(f'Price: {book_price}')
        print()
else:
    print('Failed to retrieve the webpage.')
```

I installed `beautifulsoup` and `requests`, I changed to correct directory of the file, but VScode did not provide me with any output.
This is the output it gives me:

```
PS D:\Users\Pc\Desktop\r\Menu> python book.py
PS D:\Users\Pc\Desktop\r\Menu>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141049/ddg#47360279

Answer (score 1):

Change a little bit how you retrieve the tags:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://ceresbookshop.com/fr/"
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for i, p in enumerate(soup.select(".product_desc"), 1):
        name = p.select_one('[itemprop="name"]')
        price = p.select_one('[itemprop="price"]')
        print(i)
        print(name.text)
        print(price.text)
        print("-" * 80)

else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the webpage.")
```

Prints:

```
...
58
Le souffle de la bête immonde
15,00 TND
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
59
تاريخ تونس
45,00 TND
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
60
Les dérives contraires en Tunisie
24,00 TND
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
61
Les Tunisiens qui sont-ils ? D’où viennent-ils...
28,00 TND
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks ,but Why my code didn't work ?

Comment: @rayenbenomor `book_elements = soup.find_all("div", class_="product-details")` returns empty list, so the tag/class is wrong.

Comment: @rayenbenomor Youtube channel? No... but good source is `beautifulsoup` API documentation and practice things by yourself.

Comment: ok thanks brother