# Tor failing to run with Failed to bind one of the listener ports

Tags: python, tor, stem

When I run the [example][1] from the stem documentation i get the error:

```
OSError: Process terminated: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
```

The exact code that I am running is below:

```
import socks
import socket
import stem.process
import urllib

from stem.util import term

SOCKS_PORT = 7000

# Set socks proxy and wrap the urllib module

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', SOCKS_PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Perform DNS resolution through the socket

def getaddrinfo(*args):
  return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]

socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo

def query(url):
    return urllib.urlopen(url).read()

def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
  if "Bootstrapped " in line:
    print(term.format(line, term.Color.BLUE))

print(term.format("Starting Tor:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  config = {
    'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
    'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
  },
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)

print(term.format("\nChecking our endpoint:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))
print(term.format(query("https://www.atagar.com/echo.php"), term.Color.BLUE))

print(query("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286293/make-requests-using-python-over-tor"))

tor_process.kill()
```

I have seen answers saying that there is another process running on port 9050, but runniing the command `sudo netstat -anl | grep 9050` in the terminal gives me no result.

Please feel free to suggest anything that might help.

In addition, the first example on the "to russia with love" works flawlessly.

Thanks for any help that you can give.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

check tor is installed

```
sudo apt install tor
```

Check this

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/tor
```

find and replece "yes" to "no" there

```
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
```

stop the daemon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tor stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Was working and ran into this on Linux Mint.

Was able to get around it by by sleeping/ pausing for extended periods of time.

```py
import time
time.sleep(1000)      #usually sleep it over 10 minutes for my case
```

From what I am scraping it requires sleeping so it is perfect but I certainly can see it not helping in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using SOCKS_PORT as 7000, use below command to find the process using it.

```
sudo netstat -plnt | grep 7000
```

If you get an output something like this (see tor at the end),

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13009/tor
```

use `sudo killall tor` to terminate the tor process.

Using "sudo" and process name ("tor") to terminate a command is not the recommended way. Instead, you should use `kill pid` command where pid is process ID (13009) present in the above output.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem while using 'threading' package and here's my solution that might be handy for wanderers.

I used solution provided by best answer
and also did this:

```
for thread in threads_list:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    thread.run()
```