# requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support

Tags: python, proxy, ip, tor

I would like to try to open a page using proxy requests.
[https://stackoverflow.com/…/make-requests-using-python-over…](https://stackoverflow.com/%E2%80%A6/make-requests-using-python-over%E2%80%A6)
I have this code:

```
def get_tor_session():
session = requests.session()
# Tor uses the 9050 port as the default socks port
session.proxies = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
return session

# Make a request through the Tor connection
# IP visible through Tor
session = get_tor_session()
print(session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
# Above should print an IP different than your public IP

# Following prints your normal public IP
print(requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
```

But i see:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286293/make-requests-using-python-over-tor/33875657

Answer (score 1):

In order to make `requests` use socks proxy, you need to install it with it's dependency.

```
pip install requests requests[socks]
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that requests is using socks as a proxy and that socks is not installed.

Just run  pip install pysocks