# multiple proxy in python with tor

Tags: python, proxy, request, python-requests, tor

I've been looking for solution to have more than one proxy in python3.8.
First of all, I've found some code, but at times it worked or not. I've seen with controller, or socks5 blah blah... I'd like to have 50 proxies. I'm doing a project to university. My topic is: 'security with proxy', and my professor told me to use tor proxy.
Why 50 proxies? Why not :) I can use one proxy but how to change port 9050 to e.g. 9150 or 9051, because I've still had 'connection refused 111' or something like that. I've searched stackoverflow, and other forums, tutorials and I couldn't find solution. Please help. Thank you for advance.

EDIT:
The websites which I've seen:

- https://www.sylvaindurand.org/use-tor-with-python/
- [Make requests using Python over Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286293/make-requests-using-python-over-tor)
- https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/using-tor-with-the-python-request-library-79015b2606cb
- https://gist.github.com/jefftriplett/9748036

Because I've tried to "follow by other code" I've looked for project for Kali Linux and I found this:

- https://github.com/Pure-L0G1C/Instagram
- https://github.com/xHak9x/instabrute/blob/master/instabrute.py

From the first one I tried to find a way how to create 5 tor proxies at the same time!! Maybe this one could help you how to help me.

I found then an article (sorry I can't find it now. If I find, I'll copy link here), where I have to create a file (?) or something...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing the code you're running?

Comment: @DanielWalker done :) maybe it's not my code, but I gave links :)

Comment: @DanielWalker can you help me? please

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about tor proxies.

Comment: ok, no problem. I'm new here and how can I promote my question?

Comment: One thing that's going to hurt you is that your question is pretty open-ended (i.e., "how do I do this?" kind of question).  StackOverflow is best suited for specific questions such as, "Here's my code and here's the error message I got; what did I do wrong?"

Comment: ok, i got this, but now I'm trying to figure out how to do this :D