# Proxies with Python 'Requests' module (Not Working)

Tags: python, python-requests, httprequest

I am trying to create a proxy tester, I have been trying to trouble shoot this for days and can't seem to figure out the issue.  Every time I run it, no matter what the proxy is (I've tried many) I get the error

> "requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='advanced.name', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /freeproxy (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to
> proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7f9a7e0ea400>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -2] Name or service not known')))"

The message sounds like the proxy is bad but I've tried a boat load that I know work.  Here is the code I have

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

proxy = {
    "http": "http//132.145.54.142:1080",
    "https": "https//132.145.54.142:1080"

}

proxy_Test = requests.get("https://advanced.name/freeproxy", headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
print(proxy_Test.status_code)
if proxy_Test.status_code == 200:
    print("this proxy is good:" + str(proxy).replace("{", " ").replace("}", "").replace("'", ""))
else:
    print("This proxy is no good")
try:
    x = requests.get("http://www.google.com", headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
except Timeout:
    print("error found")
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in you code.lack of colon in `"http": "http//132.145.54.142:1080"`.it should be `"http": "http://132.145.54.142:1080"`

Comment: Hmm, when I run it it actually waits the given time for a timeout but then still throws the error.  If the proxy is bad it should just print "This proxy is no good".  I've tried about 10 different proxies as well.

Comment: due to you proxy `132.145.54.142:1080` is available on the internet.I try it myself.first you can not set http and https as same port.second you proxy not setup well.you can test it through `curl -v  -x https://132.145.54.142:1080 ifconfig.co` or other program.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide your ip adress, you can use torrequest instead of requests:

```
pip install torrequest
```

Example code ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286293/make-requests-using-python-over-tor)):

```
from torrequest import TorRequest

with TorRequest() as tr:
    response = tr.get('http://ipecho.net/plain')
    print(response.text)

    tr.reset_identity()

    response = tr.get('http://ipecho.net/plain')
    print(response.text)
```

You need to install [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/) first.

Comment: I want to use it for account creations and what not.  Tor requests will get rejected

Answer (score -1):

This website is filtered in your country, and the proxy you've set:

```
proxy = {     "HTTPS": "http://95.66.151.101:8080" }
```

Did not work either, so you have to find another proxy

Comment: Nope, they definitely work and they are from the USA, they should work.

Comment: Are you sure?Then we will see what's the problem here